# Mongodb java: Perist POJO class with generic field

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a POJO class which looks like this-

```
public class CacheEntity<V> {
  private String cacheId;
  private V value;

  public static final String ID_KEY = "cacheId";

  public CacheEntity() {
  }

  public CacheEntity(String cache_id, V value) {
    this.cacheId = cache_id;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public V getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(V value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getCacheId() {
    return cacheId;
  }

  public void setCacheId(String cacheId) {
    this.cacheId = cacheId;
  }
}
```

I am using official driver mongodb-driver-sync version 3.8.1

As mentioned in the documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/), I am using CodecRegistry with automatic PojoCodecProvider. I am getting the following error when I try to persist this entity.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: CacheEntity contains generic types that have not been specialised.
Top level classes with generic types are not supported by the PojoCodec.
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.encode(PojoCodecImpl.java:93)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:398)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:377)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writeDocument(BsonWriterHelper.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayload(BsonWriterHelper.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encode(CommandMessage.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:244)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:444)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:200)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommand(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:418)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBulkWriteBatch(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:256)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$700(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:200)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:419)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:193)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:960)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeReplaceOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:602)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.replaceOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:578)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.replaceOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:567)
```

What can I do to make this work? Thank You.

Comment: Top Level generic classes aren't supported by the PojoCodec as type `V` is erased away to Object. Is `CacheEntity` embedded in another POJO? If so I would expect that to work.

Comment: Currently it is a top level entity. I am trying to persist it directly. But I can try wrapping it in another class

Answer (score 3):

There are following options to make it working.

#### By subclassing

If you subclass with concrete generic type each time, it works:

```java
public class MyClassCacheEntity extends CacheEntity<MyClass> {}
```

#### By using `BsonDocument` + Jackson

To avoid subclassing you can try store arbitrary objects as `BsonDocument`-s and serialize/deserialize them using Jackson:

```java
public class CacheEntity<V> {
  private String cacheId;
  private BsonDocument rawValue;

  // [...]

  // sets the value
  public void withValue(T o) {
    this.rawValue = BsonDocument.parse(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(o))
  }

  // recovers the value
  public T value(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(this.rawValue.toJson(), clazz);
  }
}
```

This works until you avoid getters/setters convention for `withValue()` and `value()` methods, otherwise Mongo starts to complain about the same generics issue.

#### Same with pure bson

I think, you can also try to do it the same as above using  `org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodec` which you can either create or extract from the current mongo codecs registry. If you know in advance and give it the real class, it shouldn't complain about generics.

Comment: Both these solutions require changing the data model itself. Is there no way to solve this problem without doing that? I have lots of user data stored in Mongo in this way, that I don't want to migrate. I really think there should be a way to provide a codec to handle this situation. In my case, my `CacheEntity` class is in fact embedded inside another class, which is the top level POJO. But still, I get this problem.